# How to check for multiple radio button selections?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a question form that I want to validate using jquery.  My form looks like this:

```
       <form id="question_answer_form" action="submit_answers.php" method="post">       
            <table class="zebra-striped">
                <tr>
                    <td >Question 1</td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="question_answer1" value="1"> Yes
                        <input type="radio" name="question_answer1" value="0"> No
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td >Question 2</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="question_answer2" value="1"> Yes
                        <input type="radio" name="question_answer2" value="0"> No
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td >Question 3</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="question_answer3" value="1"> Yes
                        <input type="radio" name="question_answer3" value="0"> No
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td colspan="2"><input class="btn success" type="button" value="Submit" id="questions"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
       </form>
```

Jquery call

```
    $("#questions").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Check radio button status and notify...;
    });
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to each radio some class for example "test_radio" 
then check

> $(".test_radio:checked").length > 1

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Validation plugin is a fantastic tool for all sorts of form validation.  Its got all sorts including validating multiple radio buttons.

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/